# Everyone has superpowers, depending on what country they are in. What is the effect?

Tags: society, magic, super-powers

So, there I was. Standing in a bustling street, and there's a blue flash, followed by a green flash, and everyone started rubbing their heads.

All of a sudden, people start catching fire. But they don't seem harmed.

I find a part of myself that wasn't there before.  I flip some kind of mental switch, and my hand bursts into flames, but it feels pleasantly cool.

On the news that night, was the revelation that almost everyone got powers at the same time.

None of the powers seem to heal at all.

It seems to be that the more people in the country, the more powerful the powers given.

People from China are able to turn into extinct animals at will, while the people of the Falkland Islands are able to make bread taste like whatever they like.

The exceptions are Antarctica, which has given research scientists nigh invincibility and regeneration, people at sea, who are able to telekinetically control salt water, and people in space who are able to shoot a seemingly infinite amount of any metal at will.

Comment: Telepathically control salt water? Doesn't telepathy require a mind on both ends? Do you mean telekinetically?

Comment: Is there a specific question here?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr I meant telekinetically

Comment: I find your title unclear and would like to request the following clarification: Is the case A) *All people on the world receive a superpower at the same time, this superpower is based on where they are in the world*, meaning that they keep their powers when moving somewhere else OR B) *Based on where they are in the world, people receive different superpowers*, meaning they *switch* powers depending on where they go? Thank you

Comment: Further question: What powers do children get? If, say, two people from different countries had a child would it inherit both powers, one power at random, no power or a different power?

Comment: I think this is too broad.

Comment: @dot-sp0t They get a superpower, depending on where they are at the time of the 'Flash'

Comment: @Joe Bloggs Upon receiving their powers in the flash, everyone's chromosomes became tied to their powers. The least powerful (and therefore dominant) chromosome that someone has will be the power they receive.

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities:

- Racism based on magical ability might grow, possibly just based on jealousy of others' abilities or fear of their abilities.
- One nation with more powerful or more useful abilities might push to control the other nations.
- One nation may grow superior and close off their borders to every other nation.

Your options are basically limitless, but I would look at group/nation dynamics throughout history. At the same time in history the technologically advanced Ancient Romans existed with the "German Barbarians". The Germans lived in tribes and the Romans sought to conquer them because they were uncivilized and an easy target.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that would happen is that what country you came from would suddenly become much more important. Nationalism would rise. Overtime being a citizen of a country might become possessive at certain set  of abilities. Having those abilities is what would make you a citizen of a particular country. People would form National identities not on the basis of race  or language but on what abilities they had. If you watch the show avatar The Last Airbender. You might have some idea of what this might look like.